# Props error on DateTimePicker component using react-widgets

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form, react-widgets

I have this simple reusable DateTimePicker component using react-widgets that I am building.  Its quite as basic as it can be but I don't have an idea why it throws this error eventhough I had accommodated the rest of the properties inside the DateTimePicker and had spread across in the DateTimePicker Props.

The error was this, which looks like the props did not spread across the DateTimePicker

```
Type '{ as?: any; children?: ReactNode; className?: string | undefined; content?: ReactNode; control?: any; disabled?: boolean | undefined; id?: string | number | undefined; ... 6 more ...; onChange: (event: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<DateTimePickerProps>'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

Below is the code for my **DateInput.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { FieldRenderProps } from "react-final-form";
import { FormFieldProps, Form, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { DateTimePicker } from "react-widgets";

interface IProps extends FieldRenderProps<Date, HTMLElement>, FormFieldProps {}

const DateInput: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  input,
  width,
  placeholder,
  meta: touched,
  error,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
      <DateTimePicker
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={input.value || null}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        {...props}
      />
      {touched && error && (
        <Label basic color="red">
          {error}
        </Label>
      )}
    </Form.Field>
  );
};
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of `DateTimePicker` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-widgets` expects `id` prop with a type of `string | undefined`.
However, in your case, the type of the `id` is `string | number | undefined`.

One possible solution would be to convert `id` prop to the string and pass it down to the DateTimePicker component:

```
const DateInput: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  input,
  width,
  placeholder,
  meta: touched,
  error,
  id,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
      <DateTimePicker
        id={String(id)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={input.value || null}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        {...props}
      />
      {touched && error && (
        <Label basic color="red">
          {error}
        </Label>
      )}
    </Form.Field>
  );
};
```